# How can we hide the user has joined/left the Team in the channels?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a Team  with hundred of members and several channels. New members joined and other leave the Teams and it becomes really annoying seeing this messages "xxxx has leave the team”, “yyyy has joined the team” on the conversion TAB.

How can we disable this function?

Regards

Comment: There is no way out to turn off these messages. Check uservoice, vote for it if you want this feature in future.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there isn’t a way to turn off system messages in team edition!
Since many such requests have been made, I think this function will be available soon.

If you want to protect your users’ id´s, you could turn off showing email addresses and full names.
Go in the System Console > Settings > Privacy.

Comment: HI @Michael Maier, thanks for your reply. Where can I find the "System Console"?. Regards

Comment: @vcima Actually not quite sure sorry, maybe this will help: https://docs.mattermost.com/deployment/advanced-permissions.html   There u can see what the System Console looks like. Have a nice day